# Cannot fix TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I tried few solved questions on stackoverflow but couldn't make it work. Can someone kindly help me to fix this. I am using Flask for one of my project and this is the error I am getting. Following is the code and traceback.

The code is related to line 12 in sqlutils.py.

```
import hashlib
import os
import oursql
import uuid
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from mainapp import app

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+oursql://'+os.environ.get('DB_USR') \
                                        + ':' + os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD')+'@'\
                                        + os.environ.get('DB_HOST') + '/school_new'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mainapp import app
  File "/home/osboxes/school/mainapp-web/mainapp/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    import views
  File "/home/osboxes/school/mainapp-web/mainapp/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mainapp.students.availability_students import add_availability, delete_availability, get_availabilities_by_username, \
  File "/home/osboxes/school/mainapp-web/mainapp/students/availability_students.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .sqlutils import build_where, build_set, get_connection
  File "/home/osboxes/school/mainapp-web/mainapp/students/sqlutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    + os.environ.get('DB_HOST') + '/school_new'
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: os.environ.get('DB_HOST') is probably None

Comment: print all these: `os.environ.get('DB_USR'), os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD'), os.environ.get('DB_HOST')` 1 of them is None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide some sensible defaults for when the environment doesn't contain your settings:

```
DB_HOST = os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
DB_USR = os.envrion.get('DB_USR', 'root')
DB_PASSWD = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD', 'sekret')

DB_URL = 'mysql+oursql://{}:{}@{}/school_new'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL.format(DB_USR, DB_PASSWD, DB_HOST)
```

Or raise an error if critical settings are not provided:

```
DB_HOST = os.environ.get('DB_HOST')
DB_USR = os.environ.get('DB_USR')
DB_PASSWD = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD')

if not all([DB_HOST, DB_USR, DB_PASSWD]):
   raise Exception('Missing Database Environment Variables')
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug try:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
    'mysql+oursql://' + os.environ.get('DB_USR','NO_USER') \
    + ':' + os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD', 'NOPASSWD')+'@' \
    + os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'NO_HOST') + '/school_new'
```

And log/print `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`.

Comment: Its not even letting me print in shell. Whenever I do it pops up error in env shell.

Answer (score 0):

When the key you request the value of doesn't exist in the dictionary, [.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) returns `None`.

So, given the error you're getting, it appears that there is no `'DB_HOST'` in `os.environ`.

If there's some default value (`'localhost'` perhaps?) that makes sense for you to use in such cases, you can add it as the second parameter in your call to `.get()`, and then that value will be returned rather than `None` whenever the key doesn't exist.

```
os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
```

And if it's at all possible that the other keys (`'DB_USR'` and `'DB_PASSWD'`) might not exist, you should either add appropriate default values for them, or employ some form of error handling.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, [using `.get()` on a dictionary will result in a `None` if the value does not exist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> **get**(key[, default])
>
> Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

It's a dictionary, so you could even do things like `os.environ['DB_HOST']` instead of using `.get()`. Why? Because then you'd get an error on startup if the value didn't exist! Which might be nifty in something so critical to your application. :)

Okay, so apparently `os.environ.get('DB_HOST')` in your code has returned `None`. Why is that?

[`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) gives you access to the operating system's environment variables from the shell. Apparently, the variable `DB_HOST` hasn't been set anywhere!

To solve your problem, you'll have to set the environment variable for `DB_HOST` in your OS, or else provide the information in some other way. Personally, I like passing these values in as command-line arguments via [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), but that's up to you!

---

In case you really want to use the OS's environment, I'll give you an example of setting a variable in bash (my shell). You'd have to look up parallel instructions for other shells.

From the bash command line:

```
$ export TEST_VAL="My hovercraft is full of eels."
$ python
(...)
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['TEST_VAL']
'My hovercraft is full of eels.'
```

Note that use of `os.environ` in Python cannot *set* a new value for this variable outside of its own interactions. That is to say:

```
>>> os.environ['TEST_VAL'] = "new value"
>>> exit()
$ echo $TEST_VAL
My hovercraft is full of eels.
```